# Django, How to repeat a single field multiple time

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Imagine i have a class =  SkillModel in model.py where can specify their skills, so a user can have multiple skills but i have single field in table ,,,so how can i repeat this to gain multiple values(skills) from user.

[here is have preference factors where user will put there preference such as hark working or any xyz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvZID.png)

so how can i made a model where can take multiple values ...like multiple skills

[SO HOW CAN I MODIFY THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKkDD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgreSQL you could use an Arrayfield.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Or use an extra model that binds the user to a factor

```
class UserFactor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    factor = models.ForeignKey(Factors, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And to make life easy use django-taggit:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit